# How do I combine multiple observations for a given variable using R?

Tags: r, distribution, frequency

I am providing a sample of my data as under:

```
Species Individuals  
A   1  
A   2  
A   3  
B   1  
B   2  
B   3  
C   1  
C   2  
C   3  
A   1  
B   2  
C   3  
C   1  
B   2  
B   3  
A   1
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
Species  Frequency  
A               8  
B              13  
C              10
```

Is it possible to do this using R ?

Comment: You can find all the examples of how to do this operation in the link Henrik provided. They are almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
aggregate(cbind(Frequency=Individuals)~Species,df, sum)
#    Species Frequency
#1       A         8
#2       B        13
#3       C        10
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Frequency=sum(Individuals)), by=Species]
#     Species Frequency
#1:       A         8
#2:       B        13
#3:       C        10
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the intuitive flow of `dplyr` pleasing. The added advantage is that the result still is data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Frequency=sum(Individuals))
#   Species Individuals
# 1       A           8
# 2       B          13
# 3       C          10
```